# what does PHP substr do on utf-8 string?

Tags: php, string, encoding

Reminded by Sammitch, I double checked my input with Hexinator binary editor and found my input was wrong. So this question is closed.

_______Original Question:_______

I have a UTF-8 string as:

```
<?php $str = '收听'; ?>
```

In binary, $str is:
E694B6E590AC

```
<?php $a = $str[1]; ?>
```

or

```
<?php $a = substr($str,1,1); ?>
```

I got $a as binary 90, NOT 94.

Walk through $str[0] to $str[5], I got new binary:
E590ACE8AFB4

They are identical to url encoding of $str:
%E5%90%AC%E8%AF%B4

So what did substr actually do here internally on the UTF-8 $str?

By the way, I don't want to use mb_substr to cut a UTF-8 string.

I don't understand why $str[0] is E5, not E6; $str[1] is 90, Not 94.

I also have a function as below which do substr or index of string on utf-8 string.

```
<?php
/**
 * urlencodes complete string, including alphanumeric characters and multibyte characters
 * @param string $string the string to encode
 */
function urlencode_all($string){
    $chars = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
        $char = (string)dechex(ord($string[$i]));
        if(strlen($char)==1) $char = '0'.$char;
        $chars[] = '%'.$char;
    }
    return implode('', $chars);
}
?>
```

Can someone explain what did substr do here?

Comment: Works for me. See [https://3v4l.org/HKblE](https://3v4l.org/HKblE)

Comment: Have you considered that your input string simply is not what you think it is and the output is valid?

Comment: @Sammitch Thank you. I double checked my input with Hexinator binary editor and found out the input was wrong. So the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

> By the way, I don't want to use mb_substr to cut a UTF-8 string.

Welcome to hell.

There are two core problems:

#### 1. Any UTF codepoint can be comprised of between 1 and 4 bytes in UTF8.

In the case of your example each symbol is a 3-byte UTF8 sequence, but it's perfectly valid to have a mix of any length byte sequences in a single string. This makes it impractical to use `substr()` since it operates on numbers of bytes.

**Solution:** Use [`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)

#### 2. Any *single symbol* you see might be composed of *multiple codepoints*.

While `mb_substr()` may be able to slice a UTF8 string into individual codepoints there's a chance you could corrupt the string by breaking a particular codepoint sequence.

Eg: T҉̲̰ọ͕͉n͘y͕̣̹͚͇̗ ͉̺̘̣̟t͍̹̟̙h̬̰̪̭̘͎̥e̛̮ ̨P͕͖̩o͡n̛͕̤̥̼͔̩͎y͍̤͠ is actually:

```
00000000  54 d2 89 cc b2 cc b0 6f  cc a3 cd 95 cd 89 6e cd  |T......o......n.|
00000010  98 79 cd 95 cc a3 cc b9  cd 9a cd 87 cc 97 20 cd  |.y............ .|
00000020  89 cc ba cc 98 cc a3 cc  9f 74 cd 8d cc b9 cc 9f  |.........t......|
00000030  cc 99 68 cc ac cc b0 cc  aa cc ad cc 98 cd 8e cc  |..h.............|
00000040  a5 65 cc 9b cc ae 20 cc  a8 50 cd 95 cd 96 cc a9  |.e.... ..P......|
00000050  6f cd a1 6e cc 9b cd 95  cc a4 cc a5 cc bc cd 94  |o..n............|
00000060  cc a9 cd 8e 79 cd a0 cd  8d cc a4                 |....y......|
```

**Solution:** Uhh... let me know if someone figures this one out.

As far as I know Chinese doesn't do much with multiple codepoints [I'm not an expert, though] so you're *probably* fine with `mb_substr()`. [until you're not]

#### Lastly

The Wikipedia article on UTF8 is really great if you want to understand how UTF8 works and I recommend that everyone that has to deal with UTF8 read it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: For  $str which binary is E694B6E590AC, file_put_contents($file,$str[0]), why I got byte E5, Not first byte E6? mb_substr is ok. But question here is Not about cutting a string.